# I want to process multiple files using python multiprocessing, but below code processing all files again and again

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote below code to process multiple files using multiprocessing but it is processing all files again and again for each process which I don't want, I want to process each file once throught the program is there any solution for it??

---

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool



def process_document(process_id):
    folderPath = '<path where all folders are there which have multiple files>'
    for subFolderRoot, foldersWithinSubFolder, files in os.walk(folderPath):
        l = []
        for fileName in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(subFolderRoot, fileName)
            l.append(file_path)
           
    return l


if __name__ == '__main__':

    work = range(int(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    p = Pool(len(work))
    p.map(process_document, work)
```

Comment: Your loop iterates over all the files, but you are also calling the loop many times?

Comment: Yes carlos, I want to restrict that..I want to iterate bt only once for each file among all processes..cz when every process starts it again picking up the files which are already processed by previous process that's y my computation time and space complexity gets increased. I want some efficient solution to prevent this thing.

Comment: Make a queue that each job takes a filename from